# Java Class loading phase

Tags: java, jvm

Since class loading can be split into Bytecode loading, Linking (verification, preparation, optional resolution) and initialization, which one of these stages is responsible for allocation and instantiation of type structures in the method area, that are later used by `Class` object?

Comment: Lets say you found a solution where this made a difference (I can't think of one), wouldn't it be better to write the code so it doesn't matter because its something which could change in ways you can't predict?

Comment: Sure, I get your point. I know it should be abstracted out and noone should care, nevertheless I want to know :)

Comment: In that case I sugegst reading the code. ;)  The problem you have is that the data structures are re-organised and restructured while the code is running. If you use `-XX:+PrintCompilation` you can see that even in a simple program code can be optimised after starting and later de-optimised and re-optimised. In more complex cases like OSGi a method which was inlined can be removed. The entire process is highly dynamic and you are likely to find little bit of work are done at each stage and while the program is running.